# Maven plugin config goal inside execution tag

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I noticed maven plugins has goals and they are bound to different phases. But it seems some goals will only be executed after we explicitly config them in side `execution` tag. For example, maven-jar-plugin has two goals `jar` and `test-jar`. If you don't config `test-jar` goal explicitly inside `execution` tag then it will not be executed. It will only be triggered with below config where `test-jar` is explicitly config inside `execution` tag

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But for goal `jar` whether you config it with `execution` tag or not, it will always be triggered. In this case, I wonder to trigger a goal of a plugin should we config it inside `execution` tag or not? I didn't see official doc has any clarification on this either. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jar` goal is by default bound to the [default life cycle](https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging) (jar) so it's triggered `automatically`.

All plugins which are bound by the default life cycle (for example maven-compiler-plugin etc) will run automatically during a build.

Any other goals which are not bound will not run automatically and have to be bound manually if needed.

All goals like the `jar` goal of the maven-jar-plugin should never being bound manally... because they are already bound to the life cycle.

Furthermore you should always check the documentation of the appropriate plugin (here the [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html)) and check the goal page for the text: `Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: package.`

This means you can omit the `<phase>..</phase>` part of your configuration because the plugin knows the life cycle phase when it should start.